# Linear Algebra prerequisite for Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Okay so I am studying Baby Rudin on my own and I completed the first 15 exercises of chapter 1. However problems 16-17 are proving really difficult for me. I have no background in linear algebra whatsoever. My question is this:
Do I simply need to spend more time on these problems. Or do I need to supplement my study of Rudin with some additional material on linear algebra.

Comment: Dot products would help for #17. In general you don't need Linear Algebra for Rudin, though. I wouldn't worry.

Comment: If you are only doing chapter 1-6, I don't think linear algebra is too important if you take stuff like the triangular inequality and properties of absolute value as granted.

Comment: Okay thank you, I think I just need to be more patient with these problems.

Comment: Instead try to understand 1.19 and 1.20, you really need those in later chapters